# React admin: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: docker, production-environment, react-admin, api-platform.com

I'm using the [react admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/) together with [API Platform admin](https://github.com/api-platform/admin) and I couldn't figure out why I get this error on production but not in local docker environment:

[image]

```
react-dom.production.min.js:3282 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at l (fieldFactory.js:21)
    at p (List.js:83)
    at beginWork (react-dom.production.min.js:2902)
    at o (react-dom.production.min.js:4051)
    at a (react-dom.production.min.js:4068)
    at x (react-dom.production.min.js:4296)
    at w (react-dom.production.min.js:4263)
    at b (react-dom.production.min.js:4254)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.production.min.js:4563)
    at xn (react-dom.production.min.js:1684)
```

I am using the [demo example](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/demo) and have no clue of which element is causing this issue: is there a way to know which element is responsible for the error?

Comment: How did you run the demo with API platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the error was with me wrongly providing custom routes as shown [in the demo](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/examples/demo/src/App.js#L69) and then using API platform's [authentication example](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/#authentication-support) to set those custom routes:

```
            switch (result.status) {
                case 401:
                    return Promise.resolve({
                        api: result.api,
                        customRoutes: [{
                            props: {
                                path: '/',
                                render: () => <Redirect to={`/login`}/>,
                            },
                        }],
                    });

                default:
                    return Promise.reject(result);
            }
...
            <HydraAdmin
                title=""
                dataProvider={dataProvider}
                customReducers={{ theme: themeReducer }}
                customSagas={sagas}
                customRoutes={customRoutes}
                authProvider={authProvider}
                dashboard={Dashboard}
                loginPage={Login}
                appLayout={Layout}
                menu={Menu}
                locale="en"
                i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            >
...
```

Providing a wrong route to the API platform trigered that error.. So I fixed it by removing the custom routes: `customRoutes={customRoutes}`